# Telling which group's mean value is higher using lm()?

Tags: anova, linear-model, mean, regression-coefficients

We have groups A,B,C and we try to see if their means are different. Below are the summary of the linear model fitted.Below you can see group A is the reference group.Can I say checking coefficient estimates that,since difference between groups A and C are significant, that mean of A is higher than C because coefficient of C would be (7.46000 - 0.36200) which is less than A's coefficient? I guess we can not say anything about A&B since the difference is not significant.

````r
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ as.factor(g), data = example.data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.5980 -0.5600 -0.0550  0.6593  3.0020 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        7.46000    0.09587  77.815   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(g)B     -0.20500    0.13558  -1.512    0.132    
as.factor(g)C     -0.36200    0.13558  -2.670    0.008 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9587 on 297 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.02358,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.017 
F-statistic: 3.585 on 2 and 297 DF,  p-value: 0.02893

```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this output, there is evidence that the population mean for A is higher than the population mean for C because of the small p-value on the coefficient for C. The estimated *coefficient* for C is -.362; the *mean* of group C in the sample is 7.46-.362. The mean of group A in the sample is 7.46. I just wanted to clarify some terminology since you appeared to be confusing "mean" and "coefficient".